# Is there a Linux CLI tool to resize ext3 partition without data loss in simple step?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems

There are plenty of tools like `parted` and `fdisk` but all of them are not very user friendly. Something like Partition Magic but for CLI Linux? Something that automatically will adjust partition table, check FS, temporarily remove journaling (if needed) etc? In one command line :)

Comment: CLI *and* User Friendly? That's quite optimistic. Command lines are designed for scripts; GUIs are for humans.

Comment: If you give us more information on why you want _both_ CLI _and_ user friendly, we could probably find a better solution. If you need to do this on a remote server, you could connect using ssh -X and run gparted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parted already does everything that you mention, and it's as user friendly as you'll get from a CLI tool (but I'd love to be proved wrong here).

Fdisk does not operate on filesystems - it only operates on partitions, AFAIK, which means it's probably not what you're looking for.

For X, I'm sure you already know about gparted.

Comment: AFAIK, parted does not touch filesystems anymore, though Gparted still does.

Comment: I am not sure if you read the question completely. I know that fdisk does not deal with filesystems. My point was that these days, e.g. to increase size of ext3 partition, you need to run umount, followed by fsck, followed by fdisk, followed by resize2fs, followed by .... (you get the idea).
What I'm looking for is something like `duperparter /dev/sdb1 5TB` where `/dev/sdb1` is a ext3/4/5(joking) partition on a VM which had sdb expanded from 4TB to 5TB.

Comment: @grawity you are probably right. The parted 2.3 in the system I'm using warns of such deprecation (although it still resizes the filesystem)

Comment: @Alex I think I misunderstood what you meant by "user friendly". I'd check your current parted version to see if it still does filesystem resizing. Otherwise, if you're doing resizes that often, it can't be too difficult to write a bash script

Comment: @Alex: These days, I'm sure umount/fsck/mount isn't actually needed with modern filesystems.